# Swift Functional with Array and a Guard ... Possible?

Tags: swift, for-loop, optimization, functional-programming

Trying to make this common swift pattern more functional.

```
for object in objects.allObjects {
    guard let _object = object as? SomeTypeOfObject else { continue }
    _object.subObject(subObject, objectStateChanged: changedState)
}
```

1. I'd love to use something like "any" (instead of map) to get rid of the for loop - like in Kotlin - but that dose not seem to be possible in Swift.
2. Trying to figure out a way to include the guard in the functional representation of this block.

Feels like I'm missing something.  Am I?

Thanks

Comment: You are calling a side effect here (in the form of the function call `_object.subObject`), rather than running pure functions, so you can't replace the loop with a higher order function like `compactMap`. You could use `forEach` instead of the for loop, but that wouldn't really yield any benefits. To be able to transform this piece of code into a more functional version, you'd need to get rid of the side effect. The guard itself isn't the problem at all, the side effect is.

Comment: There's nothing functional about calling a method with a side effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common functional pattern is to `compactMap` and then call the method with side-effect in a `forEach`. This eliminates the `guard` entirely:

```swift
objects.allObjects                           // Add `.lazy` if you don’t want to build the intermediary array
    .compactMap { $0 as? SomeTypeOfObject }
    .forEach { $0.subObject(subObject, objectStateChanged: changedState) }
```

Comment: Thanks Rob.  That helped a lot.  Well written and helped me understand more than I asked.